# Dates and overloading of the <= (or >=) operator

Tags: c++

I don't know if I'm really tired but this piece of code is giving me
(logic?) problems while running unit tests. Does anything looks wrong in the following piece of code?

```
bool Date::operator <= (const Date& d) const {
    if (this != &d) {         
        if (day > d.day)
            return false;
        if (hour > d.hour)
            return false;
        if (minute > d.minute)
            return false;
        if (second > d.second)
            return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Just for testing, I replaced it with this (ugly) version and all the tests passed...

```
bool Date::operator <= (const Date& d) const {
    if (this != &d) {
        long a = (86400 * day) + (3600 * hour) + (60 * minute) + second;
        long b = (86400 * d.day) + (3600 * d.hour) + (60 * d.minute) + d.second;

        return a <= b;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Anyone could help?
Thanks!

Comment: I'd probably implement that like `return *this < d || *this == d;`, if not `return !(*this > d);`.

Comment: Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: @OliCharlesworth You're being a bit too harsh. IMHO it's a valid question on how to compare dates, while also giving information on what she/he already tried.

Comment: @NikosC.: I disagree.  This is a "what's wrong with my code" question, and in this case, it's something that should be simple enough to track down with a failing test case and a debugger (or print statements).

Comment: To the OP: I suppose that for the sake of not getting your question closed, you should rephrase it in order for it not to look like "review this code" but instead ask straight away how to efficiently compare two dates.

Comment: You forgot about months, years, and millisecond. This can produce incorrect comparison results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That cannot work. For example, if `day < d.day` but `hour > d.hour`, you'll return `false`, which is incorrect.

What you want is this:

```
bool Date::operator <= (const Date& d) const {
    if (this != &d) {
        if (day < d.day)
            return true;
        if (day > d.day)
            return false;
        if (hour < d.hour)
            return true;
        if (hour > d.hour)
            return false;
        if (minute < d.minute)
            return true;
        if (minute > d.minute)
            return false;
        if (second > d.second)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would leverage the lexicographical comparisons available to `std::tie` to implement `bool operator<` and one of `bool operator==` or `bool operator>`, then implement `bool operator<=` in terms of the other two.

```
#include <tuple>

....

bool Date::operator<(const Date& rhs) const
{
    return std::tie(day, hour, minute, second) < 
           std::tie(rhs.day, rhs.hour, rhs.minute, rhs.second);
}
```

and so on. Altenratively, you can implement `bool operator<=` directly using `std::tie` in the same manner.